# Placing MVC 4 login control on Home/index page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

First off I am new to MVC, I was a webforms guy...

I want to show my login control on my `home/index` page, but no matter what I do I run in to errors.  I have tried various techniques and have gotten many errors with each technique, so I wont list them all here.

Right now I have it set that if `Request.IsAuthenticated` then show the username else show the login form.  But the form is obviously looking at the home controller and nothing happens when I submit the login.

Any advice would be much appreciated. I have been dabbling for days on this.

Thanks :)

Here is the Code:

```
'@{
ViewBag.Title = "MyApp";
}

<p>Code for main Index Page here</p>


@model Application.Models.LoginModel
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Log in";
}

@if (Request.IsAuthenticated) {
<text>
    Hello, @Html.ActionLink(User.Identity.Name, "Manage", "Account", routeValues:     null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "username", title = "Manage" })!
    @using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm" })) {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a>
    }
</text>
} else {


<section id="loginForm">
<h2>Use a local account to log in.</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm(new { ReturnUrl = "RedirectToAction" }))
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>Log in Form</legend>
    <ol>
        <li>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)
        </li>
        <li>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
        </li>
        <li>
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe)
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe, new { @class = "checkbox" })
        </li>
    </ol>
    <input type="submit" value="Log in" />
</fieldset>
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register", "Account") if you don't have an account.
</p> 
}
@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
</section>
}
```

'

Comment: Could you post some of your code? HTML/CSS etc...?

Comment: Just added code to post.  The Controller right now is just returning a view() nothing special there until I can figure this out.

Comment: did you try to use `@Html.partial("linktologinview")` in your home controller?

Comment: Sorry, I am trying to get the ACcount/Login.cshtml to load in to a the index.cshtml, not the _loginPartial.

Answer (score 2):

you have to modify your form like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login","Account",FormMethod.Post, new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }))
```

the key is the "Login","Account" part, that tells the form to post the data to the login action of the account controller instead of the home controller. I fought with the same thing for a few hours then figured it out.

if the data does not post to the account controller (the controller that actually validates the username and password and logs the user in) it will never try to log them in.

reason is :
by default in the routeconfig.cs class sends any links or forms that do not specify an action and controller send all stuff to the Index action of the Home controller.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You should use a Child Action:

In your controller:

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult LoginForm()
{
    return View("_LoginFormPartialViewHere");
}
```

Then in your homepage view:

```
@{ Html.RenderAction("LoginForm"); }
```

In your partial view for your login form, you can strongly-type the view for your login view model, but make sure to specify a different post action for your form than the default "postback" model. This action will handle the login and only the login (so not your homepage action).

Comment: I get "Error executing child request for handler 'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper'." error

Comment: Changed the Controller to:
    
    `[ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult LoginForm()
        {
            //return View("_LoginFormPartialViewHere");
            return View("_LoginPartial");
        }`
And now the control doesnt show at all, but no errors :)

Comment: Did you call RenderAction in your homepage view?

Comment: yup:
    `@{ Html.RenderAction("LoginForm"); }`

I also tried this in the controller:
    `return View("~Shared/_LoginPartial");`
but it did not like that

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here is that you are attempting to write code without actually understanding what it does.  Without understanding what it does, you are simply left randomly changing things hoping to find something that works.  This is a very poor way to write software.

Your problem is rooted in the fact that you don't understand that MVC is merely generating HTML, and without understanding what that HTML is supposed to be doing, you have little hope of randomly figuring this out.

First, MVC has no concept of a "login control".  They're just HTML form fields, and they sit within an HTML form element.  Those form fields are posted to your controller using standard HTML, which means you have to ensure your form action method is correct, and that the action url is correct.

Secondly, when those form fields are posted, you have to have an action method that will receive the post.  If that action method is not the same as the action method used in the GET, then you will have to tell the BeginForm() helper where to post to.

In MVC, you can't think like Webforms and just assume everything gets done for you.  You have to do everything yourself, and make sure every link, every action, every selector, every bit of javascript, etc.. is all correct.  This is more work than WebForms, but it's also more powerful and more efficient.